# How to be notified of comments posted via the Facebook Comments Social Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently implemented the Facebook social plugin for comments on my blog. I assumed, incorrectly, that I would get a Facebook notification when someone posts a comment to one of my articles.  I was wondering if that is a possibility.

I have read references to  the use of a event.subscribe function in the javascript SDK, but I wasn't really interested in creating a javascript-based notification dingus but would rather just see the little badge in my Facebook notification window.

I'd love any insight on how others have addressed this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use this plugin to get email notification for every Facebook Comment being posted at your WordPress website https://www.heateor.com/facebook-comments-notifier

Answer (score 22):

Just add yourself as moderator under Facebook developers comments tool. That's it. You'll start getting notifications of any comments on any of your blog posts.

[image: facebook notification of comments on your blog posts]

Shorter way:

1. Open this url (am assuming you are signed into Facebook and is administrator of your Facebook app):
   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/
2. Click on settings
3. Add yourself (or any of your friend/employee) as moderator.

Lengthier way:

- Click on 'Moderation Tool' on any of your blogpost's facebook comments.
- You must be on Facebook developers page now. On this page, you must be seeing something like 'your app name' > 'the blogpost title' (from where you clicked moderation tool). Here click on your app name.
- On this new page, click on settings.
- You must be seeing a modal now. Add yourself (or any of your friend) as moderator here.

You must be getting notifications now.

Comment: How to receive notifications programatically ?

Answer (score 7):

For those who have been struggling to find a way to get notified when someone sends a comment on your page, here's a (sort of) solution.

1. Assuming you've created an app for your website, add the following meta tag to your `<head>`: `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID_HERE" />`
2. Then in [Facebook Moderation Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) choose your app and click on *Settings* in top right corner. In settings, choose *Moderation rules* tab and at the bottom, you'll find an option *Closed* under *Moderation* heading. Select this option. By setting *Closed* option you basically have to approve all comments that are added to your site, but right now that's the only option how to get notified right in your Facebook without setting up custom listeners on comment.create event. That's also why this solution is *sort of* solution.
3. Also don't forget to add yourself as a moderator as Saurabh's answer suggests (otherwise you won't get any notification in your facebook).

Comment: I did the same but not able to moderate comments. I have added moderator but not a single comment is there to verify. Every comment is directly published on site.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia This post is year and half old so it's possible that Facebook has updated the way they allow users to moderate comments. Cannot say for sure whether this works or not anymore.

Comment: They are still using the same way to moderate. But I am not able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just check the [Facebook moderation tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments).  You could build some kind of notification system that pulls comments using the graph api.  I haven't seen any alert/notification system yet that somebody has else built but it would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even on the doncaprio blog, the owner has noted that

"For some reasons, notifications stopped working for some months now. I'm yet to find a fix for this... seems like an issue with fb or something."

I've come to the conclusion that I have to live with not having comment notifications.