# Facebook comments plugin - no notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I am using the Facebook comments social plugin on a site. I've followed the moderation tools instructions on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) and set a `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID">` tag. I want to receive a notification every time somebody makes a comment, and to that end I have followed the instructions in the link in the first answer to this question: [How to be notified of comments posted via the Facebook Comments Social Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336487/how-to-be-notified-of-comments-posted-via-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin).

Summarized, the solution is supposed to be "add yourself as a moderator using the [moderator tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) then you will receive notifications when a post is added to the moderation queue.

For me this does not happen. However, when somebody replies to an existing comment I DO get a notification in my Facebook account. This behavior seems odd to me.

Has anybody seen this behavior before? Is there a known work around out there? One possible work around is to listen to the 'comment created' javascript event and just manually send an email, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

I've found this bug in the Facebook bug tracker - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/575266905848137?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5216421d413e52d25949499

It sounds similar, but there has been no verification or work arounds reported there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there is no work around and this is just how the comments moderation tools currently function - no notifications except on replies. This is surely a bug, but whether the bug is that there are no notifications on comments OR that there ARE notifications on replies is unclear.

Again, here's a link to the bug report - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/575266905848137?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5217cbbc6dc793d49828864

Marking my own answer as correct

Comment: Oh man, I just spend 5-6 hours fighting and figuring out what hell is wrong with it that i do not get notification on new comments. But even i do not find comments in `Comments Mooderation tool` `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ap_id/`