# Facebook comment plugin issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am using facebook commnent plugin in my website. But facing 2 issues. I referred this link:

> [How to be notified of comments posted via the Facebook Comments Social Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336487/how-to-be-notified-of-comments-posted-via-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin)

1. **Not getting notification:** Added my self as a moderator but not getting notifications when someone comments.
2. **No comments showing in moderation tool:** There are comments in my website's articles but when I check the comment tool, I see `no comments`.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use the debug tool for the URLs that you specify in the data-href parameter of the plugin, and check if your meta data is correct. This will also clear Facebook’s cache of the OG meta data, which is likely necessary if you just added the relevant meta tags shortly. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I  checked the debug tool. It shows me all the metadata tags except for the fb app I'd.